# An easy riddle, who am I? From left to right, I hold the key to our existence

Tags: riddle

> From left to right, I hold the key to our existence.
>   From right to left, I am lack of experiences.
>   I exists somewhere in Geneva,
>   Yet rearranged, I am a Capital in South America.
>
> I held an important meeting in 1938,
>   but does not sign the agreement until 1962.
>   Given all these important details,
>   Could you tell if I am male or female?

Comment: Is this a sort of anagram?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start:

`From left to right, I hold the key to our existence.`

> Evian is a brand of water (which is the key to our existence)

`From right to left, I am lack of experiences.`

> Naive is a word indicating a lack of experience

`Yet rearranged, I am a Capital in South America`

> This feels like an extreme stretch, but as @IrishPanda points out in the comments on this answer, there is a town called Santa Maria de *Nieva* that is the capital of a *district* within Peru.

`I exists somewhere in Geneva,`
`I held an important meeting in 1938,`

> The water gets its name from *Évian-les-Bains*, on the shore of Lake Geneva, the site of the Évian conference in 1938

`but does not sign the agreement until 1962`

> The [International Agreement on the Neutrality of Laos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Agreement_on_the_Neutrality_of_Laos) was signed in 1962 in Geneva (but in Switzerland, not France as in the above)

`Given all these important details,
Could you tell if I am male or female?`

> Not really, actually. There is a possibility that "Evian" is marginally more likely to be used for a girl's name, but the results as anyone could reasonably be expected to find them are inconclusive.

Comment: and 'the capital in south america'?

Comment: @manshu That's the one I can't get, because no South American capital anagrams to my answer (or variants of my answer). But as I mention in the commented-out part of my answer, some parts only incidentally fit in the first place.

Comment: There is a town called Santa Maria de Nieva that is the capital of a district in Peru.

Comment: @Irishpanda if that's the intention in that clue, that's a bit like asking for a single county seat out of the entire US, but I've incorporated it. good lookin out!

Comment: The rest of your answer is too spot on to be wrong. I was originally looking for something akin to a state capital here in the US, but that was all I could find that even came close.

Comment: @Irishpanda I guess I'm just sort of thrown off by the fact that some of the parts of my answer seem to fit with other parts, but the parts don't seem to add up to a whole (e.g., 4th and 5th chunks of spoilertext). And then there's the whole issue of the question *technically* being about gender????????????

Comment: I would say female. Doing a quick google on it as a name brings up a lot of baby name sites, and most of them list it as a girl's name; a few mention it can be a boy's name, but usually as a variant of Evan.

Comment: @Irishpanda oh weird, I wasn't getting any results about baby names :/

Comment: Correct!  Neiva is the Capital of Huila, located in the valley of the Magdalena River in south central Colombia

Comment: No problem!  That was a quick answer thou